# How can I record terminal sesson?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

In a putty session, we can record the session in a text file. In the same way, I want to record the session of Ubuntu terminal in a text file.

Is it possible? If yes, How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check "**script**".

From "**man script**":

```
script  makes  a  typescript  of everything printed on your terminal.
It is useful for students who need a hardcopy record of an interactive
session as proof  of  an  assignment, as the typescript file can be
printed out later with lpr(1).

If  the  argument file is given, script saves all dialogue in file.
If no file name is given, the typescript is saved in the file typescript.
```